# Jenkins Service vs Jenkins Jar File Permission

Tags: jenkins, file-permissions

I have Jenkins 1.6 installed as a service on a CentOS machine.

At some point in the past the service stopped/crashed/? and Jenkins was restarted from the command line, `java -jar jenkins.war`, as the root user.

While it was running as root some plugins were updates/installed, and jobs created created/ran. Any new files created are now owned by the `root` user/group and not by the `jenkins` user/group.

Meaning, when the service was restarted Jenkins could not read these files. Resulting in plugins not running and most jobs not being loaded.

Manually restoring the permissions(`chown, chgrp`) to the plugins solves the plugin related issues.

For the jobs it's easy to spot new ones and fix them. Any existing ones that were re run and created new files are more difficult to find.

Then there may be other files which the Jenkins server created, not as part of a job or plugin which need to be changed. The errors are not always obvious, and crop up slowly over time.

Am I better adding the `jenkins` user to the `root` group? could this cause issues?

Or manually changing the permissions, hope i got them all! And fix others that  come up?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we manually changed the file permissions back to `Jenkins`. There were some immediate jobs that failed in the following days. And a few which only came up a few months later.

For the most part it worked well.